# "The type mapping for 'Instant' has not implemented code literal generation" when splitting entity

Tags: c#, .net-core, nodatime, ef-core-2.2

I need to refactor an Entity and move some of its properties to another Entity with a 1:1 relationship. However, when I create a new class and move mostly Instant type properties to it, creating `Entity1Id` as its key plus virtual navigation property between them, when I want to create a migration I get the following error:

> System.NotSupportedException: The type mapping for 'Instant' has not implemented code literal generation.

What is going on? I am doing no seeding (found this bug: https://github.com/npgsql/Npgsql.EntityFrameworkCore.PostgreSQL/issues/526)

I created a simple repository that demonstrates this behavior where you can test it with .Net Core 2.2. I'm currently on a Mac; I'm not sure if it has any impact.

GitHub repo: https://github.com/Slaviusz/EFCoreSplittingEntityProblem

### Edit:

As requested, what is actually the content of the Github repo, a code sample follows. Note that I have encountered this problem in a solution with tens of Entities but I was able to trim it down to as simple as one Entity refactoring project.

Starting with a simple Entity:

```
public class Table1
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public Instant Starts { get; set; }
    public Instant Ends { get; set; }
}

public class ApplicationDbContext : DbContext
{
    ... // other code like constructors and configure method overrides
    public DbSet<Table1> Table1s { get; set; }
}
```

Creating a migration succeeds followed by successful `dotnet ef database update`. (however to trigger this it's not necessary at all)

More details can be seen in the first commit: https://github.com/Slaviusz/EFCoreSplittingEntityProblem/commit/57562f0c978287e15d75ff1bead435501c28befc

---

Next step is to perform a refactoring, extracting the two Instant properties to secondary class creating logical relation between them.
Typical use case is to extract entity details to its own table requiring join/subselect only when details are needed.

In this case props `Instant Starts` and `Instant Ends` are moved to `Table2`.

```
public class Table1
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public virtual Table2 Table2 { get; set; }
}

public class Table2
{
    [Key] public int Table1Id { get; set; }
    public Instant Starts { get; set; }
    public Instant Ends { get; set; }
    public virtual Table1 Table1 { get; set; }
}

public class ApplicationDbContext : DbContext
{
    ... // other code like constructors and configure method overrides
    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.Entity<Table2>()
            .HasOne(p => p.Table1)
            .WithOne(p => p.Table2);
    }

    public DbSet<Table1> Table1s { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Table2> Table2s { get; set; }
}
```

All can be seen in the third commit: https://github.com/Slaviusz/EFCoreSplittingEntityProblem/commit/04fe59563bd510df26a37e5938889557b9741673

Note: Second commit is where I added .gitignore to exclude files unnecessary for the purpose of reproducing this.

At this point executing `dotnet ef migrations add Split` results in:

```
$ dotnet ef migrations add Split
An operation was scaffolded that may result in the loss of data. Please review the migration for accuracy.
System.NotSupportedException: The type mapping for 'Instant' has not implemented code literal generation.
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage.CoreTypeMapping.GenerateCodeLiteral(Object value)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design.Internal.CSharpHelper.UnknownLiteral(Object value)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Migrations.Design.CSharpMigrationOperationGenerator.Generate(AddColumnOperation operation, IndentedStringBuilder builder)
   at System.Dynamic.UpdateDelegates.UpdateAndExecuteVoid3[T0,T1,T2](CallSite site, T0 arg0, T1 arg1, T2 arg2)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Migrations.Design.CSharpMigrationOperationGenerator.Generate(String builderName, IReadOnlyList`1 operations, IndentedStringBuilder builder)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Migrations.Design.CSharpMigrationsGenerator.GenerateMigration(String migrationNamespace, String migrationName, IReadOnlyList`1 upOperations, IReadOnlyList`1 downOperations)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Migrations.Design.MigrationsScaffolder.ScaffoldMigration(String migrationName, String rootNamespace, String subNamespace, String language)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design.Internal.MigrationsOperations.AddMigration(String name, String outputDir, String contextType)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design.OperationExecutor.AddMigrationImpl(String name, String outputDir, String contextType)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design.OperationExecutor.OperationBase.<>c__DisplayClass3_0`1.<Execute>b__0()
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design.OperationExecutor.OperationBase.Execute(Action action)
The type mapping for 'Instant' has not implemented code literal generation.
```

---

What I feel is important to note is, that for the purpose of being able to test with EF Core In-Memory provider I'm using 2 constructors:

```
// constructor for mocking with InMemory provider
public ApplicationDbContext(DbContextOptions<ApplicationDbContext> options) : base(options) { }

protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder)
{
    // return if already configured (by mocking with InMemory provider)
    if (optionsBuilder.IsConfigured)
        return;
    ... // the rest of the code to init
}
```

This however results in `dotnet` tools not being able to perform cli EF Core operations (migrations, database updates). Thus I have additional class that extends the `IDesignTimeDbContextFactory<>`.

```
public class CliDbContext : IDesignTimeDbContextFactory<ApplicationDbContext>
{
    public ApplicationDbContext CreateDbContext(string[] args)
    {
    ... // code to init in cli cases
    }
}
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. While it's good to have the complete code in a repo, it would be useful to at least show *some* code to indicate what you're doing, including the migration. Unfortunately I'm unlikely to be able to help with - I don't know much at all about EF Core :(

Comment: While this is a perfectly good Stack Overflow question, it's sufficiently niche that you *may* find you need to file an issue on GitHub in the Npgsql.EntityFrameworkCore.PostgreSQL project. I'm sorry I'm not able to help you myself :(

Comment: Hey @JonSkeet, thanks for a suggestion. I have reported the problem and talked to Shay Rojansky in the Github issue https://github.com/npgsql/Npgsql.EntityFrameworkCore.PostgreSQL/issues/526.
This issue is closed and a solution is planned in EF Core 3.0. I have found a crude workaround I will post now as a solution to this question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While messing around with the problem in a test project it seems just plain removal of Instant properties from the POCO class triggers this error.

Very crude workaround is to split the removal to 2 migrations:

1. Cast the Instant props to string (varchar) in first migration
2. Finally remove the string props from the class in the second migration

Both migrations succeed and I was able to run `dotnet ef database update` with small warnings about possible data loss - which was expected as I have written custom SQL code to migrate data in previous migration where I created new Instant properties in another class.